# Reference request: monoids on ordinal numbers

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, ordinals, monoid

It is well-known that $(\text{Ord},+,0)$ and $(\text{Ord},\cdot,1)$ are monoids, but I haven't found references on these structures or other simpler ones (like $(\omega_1,+,0)$). For example, it would be useful for me to have references on submonoids, generators and similar things in these monoids.

Does anyone know of references that address this kind of structures? If there aren't too many references for this, is there a reason why this is happening? Maybe most of the interesting results about other monoids can be applied to ordinals or it is just that they are not interesting structures.

Comment: Maybe [**Ordinal Algebras**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000WERFRU) by Tarski (1956; [Internet Archive copy for borrowing](https://archive.org/details/ordinalalgebras0000tars) and [publishers web page](https://shop.elsevier.com/books/provability-computability-and-reflection/beklemishev/978-0-444-53384-5)).

Comment: I found it and it seems a good reference, but not very specific. Thank you.

Comment: Dedicated references solely focused on those specific monoids might be scarce. Books on ordinal theory will discuss addition and multiplication of ordinals. You may want to look for sections on well-ordered sets and ordinal arithmetic. Textbooks on abstract algebra have sections on monoids, their properties, submonoids, and generators. Understanding these concepts in a broader context will likely equip you to analyze them in the context of ordinal monoids.

Comment: Ok, thank you @John. I can also prove the results I need, but I wanted to know if anyone had already done it.